# Android Studio 3 Layout Editor Weird Behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In order to make things clean for you to understand i recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hf6hCq-6mA&feature=youtu.be)

The problem is that when i'm adding a Tab Layout inside another layout everything that appears in the blueprint becomes a dot in the upper left corner, leaving me with no other choice but to edit the xml itself in order to create the UI. This also happens sometimes when I add multiple nested layouts.

I'm searching like a week until now but still i can't understand why is this happening.

Comment: From a technical perspective, it's better to code in xml you know. I know it's dificult but that's the best way to go.

Comment: It's hard to remember all the properties :D There are so many!!! Even with the help of auto complete.